# Converting a URL to PDF using Python, Phantomjs / PyQt / Ghost

Tags: python, pdf, phantomjs, pyqt4, html-to-pdf

I am stuck with one problem in generating PDF from a link. I have a **https://example.com/export_html?parameter1=abc&parameter2=def**, this link will generate a HTML file with all the contents includes charts, tables & etc.

I am trying extract these contents from the above URL and save it to a PDF file. But the problem is above link takes atleast 5-7 seconds to load all its content, after loading all its content only i have to save it as PDF.

I tried **time.sleep()** function to load all the contents of PDF, but that did not work with **PyQt4** tried few stuffs with PyQt4 but didn't work for me.

Even tried with Ghost.py, below is the code i tried:

```
from ghost import Ghost
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QImage, QPainter, QPrinter
#from Pyside import *
#import PySide
#from PyQt4.QtWebKitWidgets import *

class MyGhost(Ghost):

    def capture_pdf(self):
        printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
        printer.setResolution(300)
        printer.setOutputFileName("QtPrinter.pdf")
        printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter.A4)
        printer.setOrientation(QPrinter.Landscape)
        printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)

        painter = QPainter(printer)
        self.main_frame.render(painter)
        painter.end()

ghost = Ghost(viewport_size=(1280,960))

page, resources = ghost.open('https://www.google.co.in/search?q=ghost+py+save+as+pdf&oq=ghost&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59j69i60l4.5364j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8')
ghost.capture_pdf()
```

But the above code is not working because Attribute error. Can someone suggest me with the better solution / approach ?

I am completely stuck with this generating PDF thing, i have to wait for that link to load for 5-7 seconds and then save it as a PDF file. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pdfkit. It is much simpler than using ghost. Install it from pypi with `pip install pdfkit`. The usage is below:

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_url('https://www.google.co.in/search?q=ghost+py+save+as+pdf&oq=ghost&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59j69i60l4.5364j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8', 'out.pdf')
```

For more information, check out [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit). You will need to download the wkhtmltopdf executable too.

Comment: I also tried this but as i said in the question, that link needs sometime to load all its contents or else a blank PDF will be generated if i use pdfkit !!!

Comment: Oh. Well, you could use pyautogui to open a page and click on save as.

Comment: Already doing that kind of functionality using inbuilt chrome's save as PDF function once the page is loaded but that's not I was looking for. Once PDF file is created and saved in a dir, I should serve that PDF as one click downloadable PDF file.